# PHP Recursively delete empty directories with SPL iterators

Tags: php, iterator

I'm struggling with how to delete a tree of empty directories in PHP using SPL iterators. Consider the following directory structure in which all directories are empty:

> /topdir
>
> ```
>   level1
>
>        level2
> ```

I've tried the following:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    '/topdir', RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
));

foreach ($it as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()) {
        rmdir((string)$file);
    }
}
```

But `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST` prevents the bottom level file from being part of the loop and I get the standard `Directory not empty` E_WARNING because level1 is not empty.

How do I recursively delete a tree of empty directories using SPL Iterators? Note: I know how to do this with `glob`, `scandir`, etc. Please do not offer these/similar functions as solutions.

I feel like I must be missing something very elementary here ...

Comment: Are you sure that all these directories contain nothing else but directories?

Comment: OK yes they problably are, I was able to reproduce this error with empty dir. :)

Comment: Yes. I've created the directory structure as a sanity check specifically for this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` that does the actual visiting of the child-directories. The `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` only provides the handles for it.

Therefore, you need to set the CHILD_FIRST flag on the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and not on the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/topdir', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

foreach ($it as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()) {
        rmdir((string)$file);
    }
}
```

To prevent warnings also add the `::SKIP_DOTS` flag to `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`